# Is there any way for Access 2016 to sort the numbers that are part of a "text" data type formatted field as though they are numeric values?

Tags: forms, sorting, text, primary-key, ms-access-2013

I am working on a database that (hopefully) will end up using a primary key with both numbers and letters in the values to track lots of agricultural product.  Due to the way in which the weighing of product takes place at more than one facility, I have no other option but to maintain the same base number but use letters in addition to this base number to denote split portions of each lot of product.  The problem is, after I create record number 99, the number 100 suddenly floats up and underneath 10.  This makes it difficult to maintain consistency and forces me to replace this alphanumeric lot ID with a strictly numeric value in order to keep it sorted (which I use "autonumber" as the data type).  Either way, I need the alphanumeric lot ID, and so having 2 ID's for the same lot can be confusing for anyone inputting values into the form.  Is there a way around this that I am just not seeing?

Comment: The autonumber ID should not be visible to the user, so it can't add confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using query as a data source then you may try to sort it by string converted to number, something like

```
SELECT id, field1, field2, ..
ORDER BY CLng(YourAlphaNumericField)
```

Edit: you may also try Val function instead of CLng - it should not fail on non-numeric input

Comment: A prompt to enter a parameter for "CLng(TableName.FieldName)" appears subsequent to this change and the sort later reverts to a purely text based sorting.  It appears to have worked briefly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not properly format your key before saving ? e.g: "0000099". You will avoid a costly conversion later.
Alternatively, you could use 2 fields as the composite PK. One with the Number (as Long) and one with the Location (as String).